# Best way to find intersecting trajectories

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, geolocation

I am working with GeoLife GPS dataset.  The dataset contains GPS datapoints in the format of
latitute/longitude/date(year,month,day,hour,second).  99% of the coordinates revolve around Beijing's coordinates.  The GPS users were mostly "walkers" traveling in foot around Beijing.

The entire dataset contains 18670 trajectories.  I would like to pull around 1000 or so of them which contain sporadic intersections of a given threshold.  For example if some of the trajectories intersect often but only for a very fast period of time (less then 2/3 seconds) I would like to skip them.

However, if there exist trajectories which intersect for say 30+ seconds I would like to identify such trajectories.

I want to know algorithmically what is the best way to find such a subset.

I am identifying intersections as follows.  I have created a big bounding box of 100km x 100km over Beijing's coordinates.  All of the GPS datapoints fall within such bounding box, there is no exception to it.

I have created 100m x 100m smaller bounding boxes where each of the datapoints eventually falls in.

An intersection is identified by trajectories IDs which are contained in the same 100m x 100m bucket grid.

I could go through each of the 1000 x 1000 matrix containing the 100m x 100m grids and I check if the datapoints contained in any of the 100m x 100m grids overlaps with the rest for more than the threshold.

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it.

It would be coded in Java eventually.

Comment: I don't think you'd get all the hits that way. I don't know what the sampling rate is, but suppose the object was going sufficiently fast such that the data points missed a 100m x 100m grid square? It could happen if the object travelled more than 100m between samples.

Comment: Sorry to change the description after you comment.  I have updated my requirements and what I want to do.  I thought about it and pulling just the highest intersecting trajectories was not worth it for my project so I am now focused into pulling the trajectories which have a high time of intersection (given by a threshold) e.g it would be OK to have trajectories which intersect just 2 or 3 times but over the time threshold (e.g 30 seconds)

Comment: Can you tell us more about what an intersection is? Do the walkers have to be in the same place for the same >30 seconds for it to count? Or if one walker overlaps a previous walker's route, just 3 days later, does that count? Also, do you count an intersection as being within <100m?

Comment: Hi Andy.  Intersection is considered 2 walkers which are within the 100m x 100m box for 30+ seconds simultaneously.  Similar to two trains which travel different routes, but can stop at the same station for a period of time, thus allowing some to transfer from one train to the other.  If the transfer time is too short (few seconds) nobody can transfer, but if the transfer time is 30+ seconds it can allow for a successful transfer.  In my application the intersection means two radios are within communication range (proximity), and 30+ second is required to run some protocol between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a k-order voronoi diagram and sort it by area size. Then you can also use a cluster and remove the smaller areas. A VD is also used in shortest path planning for example for a map and movement of a robot.